# How to fix variable lengths error in mblogit in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(File=c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10"),
                 Type=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A"),
                 Time=c("T1", "T2", "T1", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T3"),
                 One_count=c(15, 8, 9, 20, 11, 0, 6, 19, 22, 7),
                 Two_count=c(3, 12, 1, 6, 10, 7, 11, 5, 2, 9),
                 Three_count=c(12, 15, 10, 25, 28, 19, 16, 21, 17, 24),
                 Four_count=c(0, 7, 18, 11, 5, 2, 15, 21, 7, 9),
                 Five_count=c(3, 6, 2, 1, 9, 12, 8, 17, 10, 0))
```

in which 'One_count' means the total number of Value 1 counted in File 1.
I want to run a multinomial regression to see how different counts (One_count, Two_count...) vary as a function of Type, Time, and File. I am setting the reference category at Three_count.
I am running this code for multinomial regression:

```
value_count <- cbind('Three_count', 'One_count', 'Two_count', 'Four_count', 'Five_count')
mblogit(formula = value_count ~ Time + Type + Time*Type, data=df, random=~1|File, method="MQL", estimator = "ML", dispersion = T)
```

However, I keep seeing this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = value_count ~ Time + Type + Time *  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Time')
```

I hope to receive some help about this. Many thanks!

Comment: In your formula, the *response* ("value_count") is a one-column matrix of column names, while you'll want the like-named columns of `df` as a matrix (not a dataframe). Replace `value_count` with `as.matrix(df[value_count])` in your formula, where `value_count = c('One_count', 'Two_count', ...)`. Note though, that at least your example data throw an error when attempting to solve the regression (singular matrix).

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I tried your suggestion and I got this error ''Error in .solve.checkCond(a, tol) : 'a' is computationally singular, rcond(a)=0'' I'm not sure if there is something causing this problem?